# Oracle 12 c RAC connection issue in jboss 4.2.3 through datasource

Tags: oracle, jboss, connection, datasource

We were using oracle 11g, in jboss 4.2.3 using datasource xml file .It was working fine.Now we moved to oracle 12 c rac version. we changed the url in datasource xml file but it is giving **[org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool]Throwable while   attempting to get a new connection: null**

but using same url in jdbc connection using Class. forName(....), It is working proper.
Please help me out , why we are not able to connect through datasource xml file.

our configuration :
jboss 4.2.3
oracle 12c rac
jdk 1.6
ojdbc6.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new datasource(12c one) from the JBOSS console, rather than doing this manually.